# Why do some movies exhibit more blood and gore than others, for the same cause like gunshots?

Tags: discussion

How can [What do some movies exhibit more blood and gore than others, for the same cause like gunshots?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/109795) be improved or on topic? I changed the title to ask about movies in general, not merely the two films in my post.

Comment: It's possible that people will downvote your question because it seems 'trivial' to answer - gunshot wounds are inherently horrific and bloody and gory but many movies choose to minimize that in order to be more palatable as entertainment.  It's an artistic directorial and production choice how realistic to make fighting.

Answer (score 2):

Films can be seen either as entertainment or as art, but in either case, how things are depicted seldom matches reality.
Each scene is designed to elicit a reaction from the audience.

The way things are shown reflects the way the director wants them to appear.
One director could include a long explicit sex scene, where another would just add a fade during the kiss.  One director could show a flash of light against the curtains and the sound of a body falling, where another would show slow motion bullets and exploding wounds.

The problem with the original question, no matter how worded, is that it can't have any answer that is correct and useful.

"*The director did it that way because that's how the director wanted to do it.*" is likely the best you'll get.

Comment: It could also depend on the rating they want to get; usually lots of blood = more restricted.